# CREATE TABLE android_metadata failed

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I've develop an application which access to database in device; however, I don't know now it can't acces to database executing code lines like this:

```
this.productoHelper.getWritableDatabase();
```

This is my exception stack trace:

```
01-16 19:20:04.629: E/Database(17236): CREATE TABLE android_metadata failed
01-16 19:20:04.639: E/Database(17236): Failed to setLocale() when constructing, closing the database
01-16 19:20:04.639: E/Database(17236): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabaseCorruptException: database disk image is malformed
01-16 19:20:04.639: E/Database(17236):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.native_setLocale(Native Method)
01-16 19:20:04.639: E/Database(17236):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.setLocale(SQLiteDatabase.java:1987)
01-16 19:20:04.639: E/Database(17236):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.<init>(SQLiteDatabase.java:1855)
01-16 19:20:04.639: E/Database(17236):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:820)
01-16 19:20:04.639: E/Database(17236):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:854)
01-16 19:20:04.639: E/Database(17236):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:847)
01-16 19:20:04.639: E/Database(17236):  at android.app.ContextImpl.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextImpl.java:550)
01-16 19:20:04.639: E/Database(17236):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:203)
01-16 19:20:04.639: E/Database(17236):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:118)
01-16 19:20:04.639: E/Database(17236):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:187)
```

By the way! When I try to do this from Eclipse Emulator it runs ok but not in device.

Comment: are you creating the database in the app, or shipping a premade one with the app?

Comment: Try using adb to uninstall and then reinstall. I've had issues where old files are left and never updated when installing a later version of the app.

Comment: I think that onCreate of helper class is called recursivly (getWritableDatabase is called from onCreate(of helper) somehow) but i can only guess

Comment: this problem is specifically arising in Google Nexus One device, Its not any specific OS problem neither any other device problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [`SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS) before opening the database.

Comment: Really my problem is that now I can't open my database from my providers classes
`public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection,
   String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) { 
private ProductoSqliteHelper ProductoHelper;     
SQLiteDatabase db = this.productoHelper.getWritableDatabase();
...
`
and it happends with all my providers classes now, but I don't know why. And I've checked if my database was created and it's right! :_(

Comment: Thanx @hovanessyan but I doesn't resolve my problem; however, I think I'm not using correctly. What's the process of pen database using SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(...SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS).

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use the SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS flag when calling SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase()

Comment: Hi!

This is my code in helper and provider class. It allways has runned but now it doesn't run (in device, not in emulator).

`public ProductoSqliteHelper(Context context, String name,
 CursorFactory factory, int version) {
          super(context, name, factory, version);
          // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
 try {
  //db.execSQL(sqlCreate);
 }catch (SQLException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
 }
}`

Comment: @hovanessyan Why ask you about my database name? I doesn't work yet! I continue getting the same error whe runs my app on my device.